# bing api 2.0 sdk json samples got syntax error in Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, firebug, bing, bing-api

I just downloaded the Bing API 2.0 SDK.  There are several html files in Bing API 2.0 SDK\Samples\JSON directory.  I replaced the AppId in the JavaScript with my new AppId.  These pages run fine in IE but I got 'syntax error' in Firefox, Firebug console.  Does anyone have similar issues?  What is in the page that is causing the 'syntax error'?
Thank you very much.
Jazure

Comment: Firebug will pinpoint the line of code causing the syntax error. double-click on the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the empty script src.

```
<script id="searchCallback" type="text/javascript" src="">
</script>
```

I fixed the sample code and is now working with most browsers as seen in
http://www.pcrethinking.com/bingapi/